# `The function $(Window) is undefined` err in jquery

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, jquery

I used the `Jquery 1.9.1` and used the code to fire when browser window will get closed as

My  `JSP` will be ,

[image]

But this shows a `red underline error` like show in picture in  `eclipse`.

I don't know why I am getting this error.Can any one help me to solve this.

Don't hesitate to ask any question.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors on your actual page, or only in your IDE (which would be something else entirely) ?

Comment: How are you loading your jquery1.9.1 locally or cdn hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the code in `doc ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
   //here unload and before unload
});
```

and you have to look that your `jquery 1.9.1` is properly loading.

---

#### about error:

That is quite possible if you are using a CDN Hosted jQuery library. Try loading it locally and referencing it from there.

Comment: I'm guessing the `window` does'nt need a DOM ready event to be ready ?

Comment: @adeneo yeah just seemed at first but it might be possible that OP is using a **CDN Hosted** library.

Comment: It might also be possible that the OP is looking at a red line in eclipse, which is an IDE, and I get red lines in my IDE all the time, it has nothing to do with real life errors.

Comment: @adeneo agreed but yet it will look for library which should be available in the project i guess.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is an alias for `jQuery`. If `$` is undefined it means the jQuery library has not been properly loaded. Be sure to include it in the page before attempting to use any jQuery methods.